# How to appy discount coupon with PHP shopping cart

Tags: logic, cart

I am stuck with one of my shopping cart,
Here is my problem

A, B, C are the products already added to my cart and each have $10, $15, $5 product value respectively. Payment carried out in a for loop with each product that is first A, then B and so on. Payment is not done in a single step. If cart has 5 product, then payment will carried 5 times. These all are perfectly working :).

But, now I would like to apply discount coupon with my cart grand total then how can I handle my payment flow :(.

Extremely sorry for my bad English.

Any help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the best practice here is to do the following:

Calculate the total cost of the cart (but do not process payment)

```
totalCost = (all A) + (all B) + (all C)
```

Calculate the total discount of the cart when the coupon is applied

```
couponDiscount = 15% (as an example)
discountedPrice = totalCost * (100% - 15%)
```

Separate the discounted price for each product:

```
discounted price for all of A = discountedPrice * ((all A) / totalCost))
process payment for product "A"

discounted price for all of B = discountedPrice * ((all B) / totalCost)
process payment for product "B"

discounted price for all of C = discountedPrice * ((all C) / totalCost)
process payment for product "C"
```

And that should do it!

Basically, `((all A) / totalCost)` represents the percentage of *both* the discounted price and the non discounted price that is made up of product "A". Multiplying that percentage with the discounted price will get you the "adjusted" discount price of product "A". Then, it's simply a matter of repeating the process for each of your products.

Hope that helps! Feel free to ask questions.